# C# split string but keep split chars / separators

Tags: c#, string

I'm splitting a string by three different characters but I want the output to include the characters I split by. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: I could not find a better place to report, but this question is not a duplicate. One answer keeps the separators with the matches, and the other one keeps the separators on their own as a match

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate and closed as this one is 2 years older than the linked question?? Other one should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @watbywbarif duplicate closure direction is not just about which one is older; it's about which one is more broad/canonical and which one has better answers.