# C# split string but keep separators

Tags: c#, string

There already exist similar questions, but all of them use regexen. The code I'm using (that strips the separators):

```
string[] sentences = s.Split(new string[] { ". ", "? ", "! ", "... " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I would like to split a block of text on sentence breaks and keep the sentence terminators. I'd like to avoid using regexen for performance. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-split-string-but-keep-split-chars

Comment: Is there a reason you can't or don't want to use regex

Comment: Funny. The title of the duplicate is "C# split string but keep split chars".

Comment: @rerun: This will be ran on a very large file and regex splitting takes up to three times as long as the `String` methods.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe there is an existing function that does this.  However you can use the following extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAndKeepSeparators(this string source, string[] separators) {
  var builder = new Text.StringBuilder();
  foreach (var cur in source) {
    builder.Append(cur);
    if (separators.Contains(cur)) {
      yield return builder.ToString();
      builder.Length = 0;
    }
  }
  if (builder.Length > 0) {
    yield return builder.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like this will break for the last field?

Comment: @jfs, @pst whoops, forgot to add in the final check

Comment: `if (separators.Contains(cur))` won't compile.

Comment: @Isaac G. `using System.Linq;` (This is because `Contains` is an Extension Method from LINQ)

Comment: This is completely broken. “cur” is a `char`, “separators” is a `string[]`. “`separators.Contains(cur)`” makes no sense.