# Splitting a string and keeping the delimeters within the results

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex, string

[Reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators), it seems Regex is the solution to my problem.

This is the HTML I'm trying to split:

```
\n\t\t\t
    <td class=\"stats_name\">
        Damage \n\t\t\t

    <td class=\"stats_value\">
        53 \n\t\t\t

    <td class=\"stats_modifier\">
        (<span class=\"ability_per_level_stat\">+3.2 / per level</span>) \n\t\t\n\t\t  

    </td>

    </td>

    </td>
```

For my reasons, I need to split this on the `<td` string. This worked well enough with HtmlAgilityPack and String.Split, however the delimiter is removed and I **need it present.**

```
var statCells = rowDocument.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.Split(new string[] {"<td"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

And here's the same "function" using Regex to keep the delimeter, however it doesn't work as expected and is returning far too many strings, I think it's splitting on "<" "t" and "d" individually.

```
var statCells = Regex.Split(rowDocument.DocumentNode.InnerHtml, @"(?<=[<td])").ToList();
```

How can I use Regex.Split to split on `"<td"`?

Comment: What do you mean with split on td? How does this not work with the htmlAgilityPack? if you do: doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("td"), you will perfectly get each td node including their tagname

Comment: @Polity: Try it! It doesn't work as you'd expect because these particular TD's don't have closing elements and the content is stretched to encompass everything until the end. :)

Comment: Got it! so you're not trying to split html after all ;)

Comment: @Polity: Not any *properly* formatted HTML, no. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@"(?<=[<td])"` is splitting on every `<` `t` or `d` because that's how character classes work. Use this if you want the `<td` at the beginning of the next string (rather than the end of the last one):

```
@"(?=<td)"
```

This is going to be slower than the original solution though. If you use String.Split and just concatenate each string with `<td` then that should work the same way but faster because you don't use regexen.