# String.Split cut separator

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use String.Split without cutting separator from string?

For example I have string

```
convertSource = "http://www.domain.com http://www.domain1.com";
```

I want to build array and use code below

```
convertSource.Split(new[] { " http" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

I get such array

```
[1] http://www.domain.com
[2] ://www.domain1.com
```

I would like to keep http, it seems String.Split not only separate string but also cut off separator.

Comment: but you should split by space " " not by http, does it help?

Comment: What if the URL contains 'http' in itself? Like `http://www.http.com/`. You should first define clear rules that restrict what can be your input.

Comment: @DavidePiras I can't split by space because URL may contain spaces.

Comment: also anyway, possible duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators

Comment: Any spaces in a URL should be encoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is screaming for Regular Expressions:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)");
Match match= regEx.Match("http://www.domain.com http://www.domain1.com");

IList<string> values = new List<string>();
while (match.Success)
{
     values.Add(match.Value);
     match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] array = Regex.Split(convertSource, @"(?=http://)");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use `" http"` as separator.

Try this:

```
string separator = " ";
convertSource.Split(separator.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

The Split method works in a way that when it comes to the separator you provide it cuts it off right there and removes the separator from the string also.

From what you are saying you want to do there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators) to split the string keeping the delimiters and then if you only want to remove leading or trailing spaces from your string then I wouuld suggest that you use `.Trim()` method: `convertSource.Trim()`

Comment: instead of new[] { " " } I think you can use ' '

Comment: I can't split by space because URL may contain spaces

Comment: @DavidePiras you must include new[] { " " } because using only " " will give you compile error. No such method found...

Comment: Could you force the URLs to be encoded (e.g. use %20 instead of space)?

Comment: Yes. Encode using HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode() and then split with ''.