# Split on multiple characters while keeping the character in the result

Tags: c#, regex, split

I want to split on `'0'` and `'1'` while keeping those characters in the split result. How can I do this in C#?

e.g.

```
"012345" => 0,1,2345
```

I tried

```
Regex.Split(number, @"(?=[01])");
```

but I get `"", 0, 12345` as the result

The following seems to work, except for `""` in between splits.

```
Regex.Split(number, @"(0|1)");
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# split string but keep split chars / separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators)

Comment: Based upon the existing answer above: `Regex.Split(value, @"(?<=[01])")`

Comment: @Philip: can you post that as an answer instead?

Comment: @JamesCotter: it works fine for me when I paste this into linqpad: Regex.Split("012345", @"(?<=[01])")

Comment: @JamesManning, I cannot take credit for the answer.  This is a duplicate,  I took the solution from the original post.

Comment: @JamesCotter: his answer uses lookbehind instead of lookahead

Comment: @JamesCotter,  I have tested it and it works for me.

Comment: @philip, it may work for that example, but not in general. This must work for any combination of numbers.

Comment: try it with "1051" as the input. Sorry that the case in my question was not representative of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to simply exclude the empty elements using the regex pattern you mentioned in your post:

```
var results = Regex.Split(number, @"(0|1)")
                   .Where(p => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p));
```

This could also work. I'd like to see a more elegant approach, which I feel is what you are seeking, but it gets the job done.

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
int curInd = 0;

var matchInfo = Regex.Matches(number, "(0|1)");
foreach (Match m in matchInfo)
{
    //Currently at the start of a match, add the match sequence to the result list.
    if (curInd == m.Index)
    {
        results.Add(number.Substring(m.Index, m.Length));
        curInd += m.Length;  
    }
    else  //add the substring up to the match point and then add the match itself
    {
        results.Add(number.Substring(curInd, m.Index - curInd));
        results.Add(number.Substring(m.Index, m.Length));
        curInd = m.Index + m.Length;
    }
}
//add any remaining text after the last match
if (curInd < number.Length)
{
    results.Add(number.Substring(curInd));
}
```