# Splitting the word by word from line

Tags: c#, parsing

Here is the example line,

```
(((EXAMPLE_WORD1 - EXAMPLE_WORD2)/EXAMPLE_WORD2) * 100)
```

I want to split above line as below,

```
(
(
(
EXAMPLE_WORD1
-
EXAMPLE_WORD2
)
/
EXAMPLE_WORD2
)
*
100
)
```

How can I do the above task in C# code?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @SonerGönül He basically wants to have each character as a string in its own element. Or I think so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this :

```
string str=  "(((EXAMPLE_WORD1 - EXAMPLE_WORD2)/EXAMPLE_WORD2) * 100)";
string[] arr = str.Split(new char[]{'/','*','(',')'},SplitOption.RemoveEmpty);
```

**UPDATE1** : In previous solution , the splitter characters will remove from the arr. Maybe the better solution is here :

```
string str=  "(((EXAMPLE_WORD1 - EXAMPLE_WORD2)/EXAMPLE_WORD2) * 100)";
str = str.replace("(","#(#").replace("/","#/#").replace(")","#)#").replace("*","#*#");
string[] arr = str.Split(new char[]{'#'},SplitOption.RemoveEmpty);
```

These solution are ideas and I did not check these solutions.edit them to get better result.

Comment: This doesn't fulfil the desired output.

Comment: The only problem with this is, it will remove the characters in the split. The output requires it as well.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?=(\b|[^a-zA-Z_0-9])+)");
var split = regex.Split("(((EXAMPLE_WORD1 - EXAMPLE_WORD2)/EXAMPLE_WORD2) * 100)");
```

EDIT: Works now :)

Comment: Tack on .Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)) maybe.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is generic word splitter based on several rules then it is not a trivial task. First you need to define what is *word* for you. Like:

- word is series of letters(a-zA-Z) with acceptable separator symbol ('_')
- word is symbol ('(',')','-', '*')
- word is series of numbers with/without acceptable separator symbol (',','.' - based on culture)

and so on

Only after you define strict rules for what should be treated as *word* should you start codding.
If this is the case you can read about [finite automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) or something similar depending on complexity of your task.

**EDIT:** if provided pattern all you need then the link provided by Bert Evans's is the answer to your solution, namely Regex pattern:

```
string youString = @"(((EXAMPLE_WORD1 - EXAMPLE_WORD2)/EXAMPLE_WORD2) * 100)";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(yourString, @"(?<=[()-/*])");
```

Answer (score 0):

I extened Ali's Answer to get the exact output

```
(
(
(
EXAMPLE_WORD1
-
EXAMPLE_WORD2
)
/
EXAMPLE_WORD2
)

*
 100
)



    string str = "(((EXAMPLE_WORD1 - EXAMPLE_WORD2)/EXAMPLE_WORD2) * 100)";
    str = str.Replace("(", "{(}");
    str = str.Replace("*", "{*}");
    str = str.Replace(")", "{)}");
    str = str.Replace("/", "{/}");
    str = str.Replace("-", "{-}");
    string[] arr = str.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string strs in arr)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(strs.Trim());
    }
```

Comment: First: author actually needs symbol `/` to be printed.   Second: performance suffers from even looking at the sample, for a real-life applications with massive arrays to parse this could take ages

Comment: Corrected the answer.
You are correct, for a huge application we need to use regex

Answer (score 0):

While a regex will get you there, you may want to consider specifying a tokenizer of sorts for flexibility and/or scalability:

Here's a naive example:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(string str)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in str)
    {
        if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_')
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        else if (char.IsPunctuation(c))
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                yield return sb.ToString();
                sb.Clear();
            }
            yield return c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        }
    }
    if (sb.Length > 0) yield return sb.ToString();
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string st = "(((EXAMPLE_WORD1 - EXAMPLE_WORD2)/EXAMPLE_WORD2) * 100)";
    Tokenize(st).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```