# Split a string and keep separator string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

How can I split a string based on a string and have the resulting array contain the separators as well?

Example:

If my string = `"Hello how are you.Are you fine?.How old are you?"`

And I want to split based on string "you", then result I want is an array with items `{ "Hello how are", "you", ".Are", "you", "fine?.How old are", "you", "?" }`.

How can I get a result like this? I tried `String.Split` and

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(source, stringSeparators);
```

But both are giving the result array without the occurrence of `you` in it.

Also, I want to split only on the whole word `you`. I don't want to split if `you` is a part of some other words. For example, in the case `Hello you are so young`, I want the result as `{ "Hello", "you", "so young" }`. I don't want to split the word `young` to `{ "you", "ng" }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# split string but keep split chars / separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators)

Comment: @Ondrej Its not a possible duplicate . I want to try for words only . See the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the seperator into a match group, then it will be part of the result array:

```
string[] substrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(source, "(you)");
```

Output would be :

```
"Hello how are ", 
"you" ,
".Are ",
"you",
" fine?.How old are ",
"you",
"?"
```

---

Update regarding your additional question: Use word-boundaries around the keyword:

```
Split(source, "\\b(you)\\b");
```

Comment: Also i want to split only for the word "you". I dont want to split ifyou is a part of some other words . Example Hello you are so young .

In this case i want result as "Hello" "you" "so young" . Dont want to split the word young to "you" and "ng"

Comment: ie i want to split either by "you" or " you "  or " you" or "you " . [ without space , with space , with space in left / right etc]

Comment: string[] substrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("Hello how are you.Are you fine?.How old are you?.Hello how old are you?.Hello you are so young", "(you)");
            int s = substrings.Length;
            substrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("Hello how are you.Are you fine?.How old are you?.Hello how old are you?.Hello you are so young", "\b(you)\b");
             s = substrings.Length;
i tried the suggestion , but first one gives some result. Second one not returning anything

Comment: @JMat My bad, you ofc. need to escape the `\b` in the pattern, see the edit.

Comment: Yes Its perfect now. Just one more case to handle Case sensitiveness? How can i achieve that . Now if You is present in string it skips them since Y is in caps

Comment: @JMat without providing `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` as third parameter, the splitting is already case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(you)\b
```

Split by this and you have your result.

Comment: string[] substrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("Hello how are you.Are you fine?.How old are you?.Hello how old are you?.Hello you are so young", "(you)"); int s = substrings.Length; substrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("Hello how are you.Are you fine?.How old are you?.Hello how old are you?.Hello you are so young", "\b(you)\b"); s = substrings.Length; i tried the suggestion , but first one gives some result. Second one not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

regex replace :

`(you)` with `|\1|`

now you will have a string like this :

```
Hello how are |you|.Are |you| fine?.How old are |you|?
```

now you can simply split on `|`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

string[] substrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(source,"\s* you\s*");

This should work. Below is the output.

"Hello how are"

".Are"

"fine?.How old are"

"?"