# Split string and keeping the delimiter without Regex C#

Tags: c#, string, split

Problem: spending too much time solving simple problems.  Oh, here's the simple problem.

- Input: `string inStr`, `char delimiter`
- Output: `string[] outStrs` where `string.Join("", outStrs) == inStr` and each item in `outStrs` before the last item must end with the delimiter.  If `inStr` ends with the delimiter, then the last item in `outStrs` ends with the delimiter as well.

Example 1:

- Input: `"my,string,separated,by,commas"`, `','`
- Output: `["my,", "string,", "separated,", "by,", "commas"]`

Example 2:

- Input: `"my,string,separated,by,commas,"`, `','`
- Output: `["my,", "string,", "separated,", "by,", "commas,"]` (notice trailing comma)

Solution with Regex: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators)

**I want to avoid using Regex**, simply because this requires only character comparison.  It's algorithmically just as complex to do as what `string.Split()` does.  It bothers me that I cannot find a more succinct way to do what I want.

My **bad** solution, which doesn't work for me... it should be faster and more succinct.

```
var outStr = inStr.Split(new[]{delimiter}, 
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(x => x + delimiter).ToArray();
if (inStr.Last() != delimiter) {
    var lastOutStr = outStr.Last();
    outStr[outStr.Length-1] = lastOutStr.Substring(0, lastOutStr.Length-1);
}
```

Comment: @James I don't need to use the power of regular expressions.  It's a simple character comparison.  It feels like too big of a tool.  This problem isn't any harder than the `string.Split()` method, the functionality just needs to be slightly different.

Comment: [Many](https://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+string+split+keep+delimiter) solved that with Regex. Is there any chance in appending the delimiter when you are using the values? something like: `foreach(string token in outStrs) { string value = token + delimiter; }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
string input = "my,string,separated,by,commas";
string[] groups = input.Split(',');
string[] output = groups
    .Select((x, idx) => x + (idx < groups.Length - 1 ? "," : string.Empty))
    .Where(x => x != "")
    .ToArray();
```

Split the string into groups, then transform every group that is not the last element by appending a comma to it.

Just thought of another way you could do it, but I don't think this method is as clear:

```
string[] output = (input + ',').Split( new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => x + ',').ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is going to be the best I can do without a .Net library call that does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple to me without using Regex:

```
string inStr = "dasdasdas";
char delimiter = 'A';
string[] result = inStr.Split(new string[] { inStr }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string lastItem = result[result.Length - 1];
int amountOfLoops = lastItem[lastItem.Length - 1] == delimiter ? result.Length - 1 : result.Length - 2;
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfLoops; i++)
{
    result[i] += delimiter;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `inStr` has the delimiter at the end?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter RemoveEmptyEntries will remove the delimiter at the end because it will be an empty string

Comment: Which is not what I want.  I'll update my question to be more clear.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter can you post an exact example of the string input that you are using.. does it really include double quotes as well as single quotes..

Comment: @JohnCarpenter see my edit, something like that is what I could understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAndKeep(this string s, string[] delims)
    {
        int start = 0, index;
        string selectedSeperator = null;
        while ((index = s.IndexOfAny(delims, start, out selectedSeperator)) != -1)
        {
            if (selectedSeperator == null)
                continue;
            if (index - start > 0)
                yield return s.Substring(start, index - start);
            yield return s.Substring(index, selectedSeperator.Length);
            start = index + selectedSeperator.Length;
        }

        if (start < s.Length)
        {
            yield return s.Substring(start);
        }
    }
```