# C# splitting string

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code:

```
string FullNote = "aaa bbb ccc";
string ExistingAdminNote = "bbb";

string[] NoteDifference = FullNote.Split(new string[] { ExistingAdminNote }, StringSplitOptions.None);

for (int ii = 0; ii < NoteDifference.Length; ii++)
    Response.Write("INCREMENT: " + ii + "--" + NoteDifference[ii] +"<br>");
```

Which outputs this:

```
INCREMENT: 0--aaa 
INCREMENT: 1-- ccc
```

But what I want it to output is this:

```
INCREMENT: 0--aaa 
INCREMENT: 1--bbb 
INCREMENT: 2-- ccc
```

eg to also add the bbb into the array, at the correct index.

I know I can write some code to compare the strings etc, but is there a function that can achieve this without me having to write some custom code?

Basically I want to find the changes to the original string. It does not need to be done in this way, as long as I can find the differences between the 2 strings.

PS I do not know what the delimiter will be - it could be anything

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/521146/87698. Remember to Regex.Escape your separator first.

Comment: Per you edit about the differing delimiter, so you're saying the input could be "aaa%bbb%ccc"?

Comment: If you don't know what the delimiter is going to be, and you don't know what the values are going to be, then what you're trying to do is just not possible.

Comment: @rory.ap yes it could be anything, I am trying to find the changes to the original string, and then add the initials of the person who made the change

Comment: What is wrong with this question that warrants a downvote? Anonymous downvoters please explain

Comment: If the original string is `bbb` and whoever edits it writes `bbb` before and/or after it, then how do you know which bit the original string is? I'm not sure you've given enough information on the expected inputs and outputs - perhaps provide a few examples.

Comment: Could be "unclear what you're asking" because you didn't clarify the delimiters.  I down voted because it's "not useful" given my prior comment.

Answer (score 2):

You're splitting on `bbb` when you should be splitting on the space character.  Your delimiter string will not show up on your result array.  The delimiter needs to be the common string that separates the values that you want.

Comment: the problem is that I do not know what the delimited will be

Comment: In your example, it's the space character " ".  Will it be different?

Comment: Well, that's important info.  You should have included that in your question to start off with.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something fairly simple as this:

```
      string FullNote = "aaa bbb ccc bbb ddd bbb eee";
      string ExistingAdminNote = "bbb";

      string[] NoteDifference = FullNote.Split(new string[] { ExistingAdminNote }, StringSplitOptions.None);

      int index = 0;
      for (int ii = 0; ii < NoteDifference.Length; ii++)
      {
        ResponseWriteLine("INCREMENT: " + index++ + "--" + NoteDifference[ii] + "<br>");
        if (ii < NoteDifference.Length - 1)
          Response.WriteLine("INCREMENT: " + index++ + "--" + ExistingAdminNote + "<br>");
      }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code when OP just needs to split on the spaces?

Comment: @juunas: Please read the post: He does not know the delimiter before start.

Answer (score -1):

Use ' ' (space) charater to split your string then your NoteDifference array will have 3 elements