# How can I split the word by numbers but also keep the numbers in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I would like to split a word by numbers, but at the same time keep the numbers in `node.js`.

For example, take this following sentence:

```
var a = "shuan3jia4";
```

What I want is:

> "shuan3 jia4"

However, if you use a regexp's `split()` function, the numbers that are used on the function are gone, for example:

```
s.split(/[0-9]/)
```

The result is:

> [ 'shuan', 'jia', '' ]

So is there any way to keep the numbers that are used on the split?

Comment: @arhak has provided an answer, but to clarify: do you want `['shuan', '3', 'jia', '4']`, or `['shuan3', 'jia4']`?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder `['shuan3', 'jia4']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to actually split it per your requirement:

```js
var a = "shuan3jia4";
console.log(a.match(/[a-z]+[0-9]/ig));
```

Answer (score 3):

use parenthesis around the match you wanna keep

see further details at [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator#25221523)

```js
var s = "shuan3jia4";
var arr = s.split(/([0-9])/);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Surprised this gets upvotes. OP specified the output they need clearly and this doesn't produce that output.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = "shuan3jia4";
var arr = s.split(/(?<=[0-9])/);
console.log(arr);
```

This will work as per your requirements. This answer was curated from @arhak and [C# split string but keep split chars / separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators)

As @codybartfast said, `(?<=PATTERN)` is positive look-behind for `PATTERN`. It should match at any place where the preceding text fits `PATTERN` so there should be a match (and a split) after each occurrence of any of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Split, map, join, trim.

```js
const a = 'shuan3jia4';

const splitUp = a.split('').map(function(char) {
    if (parseInt(char)) return `${char} `;
    return char;
});

const joined = splitUp.join('').trim();

console.log(joined);
```