# Split string and keep delimiter in sequence

Tags: c#, string

Is there a clever way to do the following string manipulation in C#?

I have any kind of string and im looking for a specified delimiter. The code should divide the string in words before and after delimiter and also include the delimiter. The delimiter could be several times in a row and also could be in the start or the end.

```
// PSEUDO CODE
string = "Hello****wide****world";
delimiter = "****";

// result should be a list<string> like
{"Hello","****","wide","****","world"}
```

Comment: How about using `Split` and then `Join` methods?

Comment: How would you split them? Doesnt split only take chars?

Comment: @Sham Join will result back to a string, not a collection...

Comment: no it doesnt! Its possible to split on a string. Still problem is that i need to keep the delimiter!

Comment: try this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators

Comment: The question identified as a duplicate is not a duplicate. There is a different output required.

Comment: Since I already made the code, there are two other parsing methods: https://pastebin.com/WKmjPNdz - you can configure the output; since you did not specify the behaviour for some cases...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Regex` and the pattern is `(\*{4})`.

```
string data = "Hello****wide****world";

string[] words = Regex.Split(data, @"(\*{4})");
List<string> result = words.ToList();
```

**NOTE**

1. `*` is a keyword in regex string, so you need to use `\` to escape it.

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p3Cxdl)

Comment: Does this keep the pattern as indexes in the list?

Comment: I think is yes. you can see my c# demo

Answer (score 0):

i'll say split the string with the delimiter, then when creating the result add the delimiter after each item in the array.

```
string fullWord = "Hello****wide****world";
string delimiter = "****";

var listOfWords = fullWord.Split(delimiter);
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach(var item in listOfWords){
  result.Add(item);
  result.Add(delimiter);
}

return result;
```

Comment: How do you know if the sequence should also start or end with the delimiter ? Also, the delimiter can be twice in a row.

Comment: With this way you add one delimiter at the end oh the file, that was not there _(in the source)_..

Comment: Julo. It could or not be there in the end. Or the beginning.

Comment: @Lautaro: have you tested the code? It will always add an delimiter at the end.

Comment: Julo. I agree with you. It won’t do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. In the end, you can iterate over the `result`.

```
string input = "Hello****wide****world";
string delimiter = "****";

var listOfWords = input.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in listOfWords)
{
    if (!item.Equals(listOfWords.Last()))
    {
        result.Add(item);
        result.Add(delimiter);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
string[] words = Regex.Split(originalString, @"(?=****)");
List<string> wordsLst = words.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

User Regex to do it :

```
string input = "Hello****wide****world";
string pattern = "(****)";

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fullWord = "Hello****wide****world";
string delimiter = "****";

var listOfWords = fullWord.Split(delimiter);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
result.Append("{");
foreach(var item in listOfWords){
  if (!item.Equals(listOfWords.Last()))
  {
       result.Append($"\"{item}\",\"{delimiter}\",");
  }
  else
  {
       result.Append($"\"{item}\"");
  }
}
result.Append("}");
var stringResult=result.ToString();
```